# How to delete from 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this vector in an external file

```
1 4 12 3
13 3 22 5
14 22 2 34
222 11 3 31
```

and I want to delete x column and y row. How can I do it and print it in an external file?

It's a 2D vector with 4 rows and columns with 4elements.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    int a[100][100],m,n;
    ifstream f("mat.txt");
    ofstream b("out.txt");
    f>>n;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            f>>a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            b<<a[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        b<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read each line in the file. If it's the yth line, skip it. If not, write out each number except the xth. So there are two for loops! File IO help is available here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ .

Comment: Can you give me the code?

Comment: Have an attempt first! :)

Comment: I get it but how to put the vector in file but how to remove the column and row?

Comment: Put your attempt up in the first post! We won't bite, and it gives a starting point for improvement. And we can potentially point out why things aren't working as you're expecting. You'll get more replise, and you'll get better replies.

Comment: Done I have how to print the array in the file but I need to delete the columns and rows...

Comment: Good start! We've initialised an unnecessarily large array, though, and an unused variable m. Don't declare m, and declare the array dynamically with the new keyword. If you know it's going to be 4x4, you can hard code n=4 and an array a[4][4]. Alternatively, I came up with a solution that avoids the array entirely, actually, see answers below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, I've hardcoded values of x, y, and the file names.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream fin("in.txt");
  ofstream fout("out.txt");
  int i, j, x = 1, y = 2;
  if (fin.is_open() && fout.is_open()) {
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
      fin >> j;
      if (i % 4 != x && i / 4 != y) {
        fout << j;
        if (i % 4 == 3) {
          fout << endl;
        } else {
          fout << " ";
        }
      }
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use some container instead of a plain 2d array in case of pushing and poping from a middle of it. Try to use this https://i.stack.imgur.com/G70oT.png for picking up right or search images by keywords std,container,choose.